# Possible causes for Boost not being found by CMake in certain situations?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, cmake, cross-platform

I build a C++ project depending on the **Boost** library using **CMake** (3.4.1). Host platform is **Linux**, targets are that host and **cross-build** Android NDK.

I'm only using Boost header files and I just downloaded/extracted the boost folder (and I don't have a `/usr/include/boost` directory).

In my `CMakeLists.txt` file I declare the dependency to Boost like this:

```
find_package(Boost 1.57 REQUIRED)
```

And I configure my build like this:

```
BOOST_ROOT=/path/to/boost cmake ../src
```

Which actually **works** as expected for my *native* build.

When I now configure a build exactly the same way (only specifying some more environment variables and a CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE) CMake gives me:

```
BOOST_ROOT=/path/to/boost JAVA_HOME=/bla/bla/bla \
ANDROID_NDK=/bla/bla/bla \
ANDROID_SDK=/bla/bla/bla \
ANT=/usr/bin/ant \
cmake ../src -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/bla/bla/android.toolchain.cmake

CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1247 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Unable to find the Boost header files.  Please set BOOST_ROOT to the root
  directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory containing
  Boost's headers.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)
```

So I *believe* I did almost the same to build for the Android target but the very same method that finds Boost for the host-build doesn't work here.

I tried to set `Boost_DIR`, `BOOSTROOT` and `BOOST_INCLUDEDIR` all with the same effect. Also I've deleted *all* content in the build directory before trying anything new.

What can be *possible* reasons for this behavior? I've already tried to print `BOOST_ROOT` directly in the `FindBoost.cmake` script like this:

```
message("BOOST_ROOT: $ENV{BOOST_ROOT}")
```

With the expected behavior (writing `BOOST_ROOT: /path/to/boost`).

Of course I can cheat now and just link the `boost` folder into the `include` folder of the cross compiler but that's not nice of course and I want to find out what's going on.

Comment: Provide content of toolchain file, please. There are several toolchain settings which affects on `find_library` and `find_path` CMake commands, which are normally used in `Find*.cmake` scripts.

Comment: I take the toolchain file from the Qt Android CMake project: https://github.com/LaurentGomila/qt-android-cmake.git

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When cross-compiling, the toolchain file normally sets the variable [CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH.html). Combined with the [CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY.html) variable set to `ONLY`, `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` variable is used as effective *chroot* for `find_library` calls, so only libraries **under the given prefix(es) are searched**.

Analogue variables exist to adjust the behavior for `find_path` (used for searching include paths) and `find_program`.

THe toolchain file you use actually sets `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` at [line 1521](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/qt-android-cmake/blob/master/toolchain/android.toolchain.cmake#L1521):

```
set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH "${ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT}/bin"
    "${ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT}/${ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_MACHINE_NAME}"
    "${ANDROID_SYSROOT}"
    "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}"
    "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/share" )
```

and below sets `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_*` variables to `ONLY`. So you need to have Boost installed under one of these directories, and give hints (like BOOST_ROOT) relative to it.

Note, that Boost should be built for the target platform (Android NDK in you case), not for the platform where you cross-compile (Linux).

Comment: So that means there is no other chance but copying the `boost` include folder and (if needed) all libraries into one of the NDK folders..

Comment: Yes, it is common way for cross-compile projects - installing all required libraries under chroot directory.

Comment: *So that means there is no other chance but copying* - well, you can use `ln -s`.