# CMake cannot find libraries and package when building using Android toolchain

Tags: android, c++, cmake, pytorch, libtorch

I am working on an algorithm library that provides pre-compiled .so file for an Android application. We want to use PyTorch C++ API in our library so I put some effort on it. However I encountered some problems when trying to build with CMake.

Building works well without using `android.cmake.toolchain` provided in the NDK, and the compiled program behaves as expected. Things go wrong when I try to use `android.cmake.toolchain` to build library, the following two lines in `TorchConfig.cmake`(this file is provided by Torch) went wrong weirdly:

```
find_package(Caffe2 REQUIRED PATHS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../Caffe2) [Line 40] 
find_library(C10_LIBRARY c10 PATHS "${TORCH_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib") [Line 47]
```

Although those commands used `PATHS` to specify absolute path, CMake insists that those package and library cannot be found. I tried use `message` to print out those path and check, the files CMaKe should be looking for (`Caffe2Config.cmake` and `libc10.so`) do exist in the path specified.

I am aware that android toolchain will change the compilers to be used (to bundled clang), but I cannot see the reason why cmake behaves oddly in my case.

Comment: The problem could be that `android.cmake.toolchain` adjust `find_` commands to search only **under sysroot**. See [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35791251/possible-causes-for-boost-not-being-found-by-cmake-in-certain-situations) and my answer to it for more info.

Comment: That's the reason and the solution I am looking for, thx!