# CMake find_path fails for simple paths

Tags: c++, cmake

I am facing issue on getting cmake work with custom boost libraries for my project (relate [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61515954/cmake-findpackage-fails-for-custom-built-boost-libraries)

Its failing in `find_path` step so to debug further i tried different combinations for this find_path all failed. Even the simple query below fails for me (complete-folder-path is complete path to the folder from root).

```
ls <complete-folder-path>
main.cpp
```

part of Cmake file

```
find_path(_TEST_Path "main.cpp" HINTS "<complete-folder-path>")
message(WARNING ${_TEST_Path})
```

This prints

```
 _TEST_Path-NOTFOUND
```

What am i missing here ?

Comment: Did you try using `PATHS` instead? `find_path(_TEST_Path "main.cpp" PATHS "<complete-folder-path>")`

Comment: Still same error,https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html from the doc only the order of when HINTS or PATHS gets used is different.

Comment: Yes, but the documentation also says "*`HINTS`: These should be paths computed by system introspection, such as a hint provided by the location of another item already found. Hard-coded guesses should be specified with the `PATHS` option.*" Yours is a hard-coded guess... Do you have any sym-links in the path?

Comment: You are right `PATHS` seems more appropriate here, actually I was trying to fix another issue mentioned in the question, so tried to mimick the setup. There are no symlinks in this path this just sits under my  home folder/test/

Comment: The actual path you wrote into the `find_path` call can be significant as well. For example, if it's a path in your home directory, make sure you spell out the *entire* path, and do *not* use the `~` home directory shortcut.

Comment: yes the one i use is full path, from root (/) no aliases/relative paths.

Comment: You may also consider trying a different variable name that doesn't start with an underscore (`_`), these are typically reserved for internal CMake use.