# Building Verilator (C++) with CMake built-in NDK

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk, verilator

I tried with [this](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling-for-android) example, but nothing happens:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(cmake_simulator)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Android)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 21)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI x86)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK /home/icarolima/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_STL_TYPE gnustl_static)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE /home/icarolima/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake)

find_package(verilator HINTS $ENV{VERILATOR_ROOT} ${VERILATOR_ROOT})
if (NOT verilator_FOUND)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Verilator was not found. Either install it, or set the VERILATOR_ROOT environment variable")
endif()

# Create a new executable target that will contain all your sources
add_library(simulator SHARED simulator.cpp)

# Add the Verilated circuit to the target
verilate(simulator
  INCLUDE_DIRS "."
  SOURCES top.sv
  VERILATOR_ARGS -Wno-CASEINCOMPLETE -Wno-WIDTH -Wno-COMBDLY -cc +1800-2012ext+sv)
```

For example, if I change the `CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI` to anything else, nothing happens. It is like CMake is ignoring the NDK part of the code.

But If I change the project to another location, different things happen:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Android)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 21)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI x86)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK /home/icarolima/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_STL_TYPE gnustl_static)

project(cmake_simulator)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE /home/icarolima/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake)

find_package(verilator HINTS $ENV{VERILATOR_ROOT} ${VERILATOR_ROOT})
if (NOT verilator_FOUND)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Verilator was not found. Either install it, or set the VERILATOR_ROOT environment variable")
endif()

# Create a new executable target that will contain all your sources
add_library(simulator SHARED simulator.cpp)

# Add the Verilated circuit to the target
verilate(simulator
  INCLUDE_DIRS "."
  SOURCES top.sv
  VERILATOR_ARGS -Wno-CASEINCOMPLETE -Wno-WIDTH -Wno-COMBDLY -cc +1800-2012ext+sv)
```

The error:

```
CMake Error at /home/icarolima/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/Platform/Android/Determine-Compiler-NDK.cmake:97 (message):
  Android: No toolchain for ABI 'x86' found in the NDK:

    /home/icarolima/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147
```

I have no experience with CMake, I think that the problem is the order of the things. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, just to clarify, the way I solved it can be seen here: [Dockerfile](https://github.com/learn-systemverilog/learn-systemverilog-worker/blob/master/Dockerfile), and here: [sandbox_template](https://github.com/learn-systemverilog/learn-systemverilog-worker/tree/master/sandbox_template).

Thanks for the answers @squareskittles!

Answer (score 1):

Setting all of these variables (such as `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME`, `CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION`, `CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI`, etc.) should happen in the **toolchain** file. You may certainly experience some nasty CMake behavior by putting these in the `CMakeLists.txt` file itself. There is even a sample toolchain file in the CMake documentation you linked [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#id22).

Also, the [`CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/variable/CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE.html) variable should be set on the **command line** when you call `cmake`, not in the CMake file itself. This reduces your `CMakeLists.txt` file to something like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project(cmake_simulator)
    
find_package(verilator HINTS $ENV{VERILATOR_ROOT} ${VERILATOR_ROOT})
if (NOT verilator_FOUND)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Verilator was not found. Either install it, or set the VERILATOR_ROOT environment variable")
endif()

# Create a new executable target that will contain all your sources
add_library(simulator SHARED simulator.cpp)

# Add the Verilated circuit to the target
verilate(simulator
  INCLUDE_DIRS "."
  SOURCES top.sv
  VERILATOR_ARGS -Wno-CASEINCOMPLETE -Wno-WIDTH -Wno-COMBDLY -cc +1800-2012ext+sv)
```

Then, you should call `cmake`, specifying the toolchain file to use, like this:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/icarolima/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake ..
```

Comment: So if I want to specify the ABI, what can I do? Also, calling CMake with these arguments and this CMakeLists.txt gives me the following error: `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:27 (message):
  Verilator was not found.  Either install it, or set the VERILATOR_ROOT
  environment variable` But this error doesn't happen when I do not set the `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`.

Comment: @ÍcaroDantasdeAraújoLima As suggested in my response, you should set all of these variables (such as `CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI`) in the **toolchain** file. Also, as the error says, you must the Verilator software on your machine first, ensuring it matches the compiler/architecture you are using within CMake.

Comment: I discovered what is happening: I already have Verilator installed, the problem is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35806563/9188829).

Comment: I will mark your answer as accepted and then I will edit my question with the complete solution, thank you very much!

Comment: @ÍcaroDantasdeAraújoLima Glad it is working! If you have a more complete solution, please consider writing your own answer post to document the full solution separately from your question. Feel free to mark yours as *accepted* as well!